# Excluding Auto Generated Identity Column from Insert in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, db2, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to insert an entity in DB2 database using Hibernate.
My entity has an @EmbeddedId and the class with @Embeddedable has a field that is an auto-generated column in my DB2 table. Upon persisting the entity, it got failed with this error

```
SQL Error: -798, SQLState: 428C9
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-798, SQLSTATE=428C9, SQLERRMC=ID, DRIVER=4.9.78
SQL Error: -727, SQLState: 56098
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-798;428C9;ID, DRIVER=4.9.78
On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
Error Refeshing Firmware Level Sources :org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not perform addBatch; SQL [insert into Db2Schema.table_entity ( ID, KEY1, KEY2, KEY3, .....) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ......)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not perform addBatch
```

Here is my Entity (Just showing the part where @EmbeddedId is used)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table_entity", schema="Db2Schema")
@DynamicUpdate @DynamicInsert
public class TableEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private TableEntityKey tableEntityKey;

    ............ Rest of the entity Fields .............

}
```

Here is Class with @Embeddable Annotation:

```
@Embeddable
public class TableEntityKey implements Serializable{

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
//  @Transient
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="key1", length=254, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private String key1;

    @Column(name="key2", nullable=false, length=256, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private String key2;

    @Column(name="key3", nullable=false, length=256, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private String key3;

    ..... getters and setters go here ................

}
```

Hibernate Dependencies in POM.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the DDL

```
CREATE TABLE
    TABLE_ENTITY
    (
        ..... REST OF THE COLUMNS OF THIS TABLE .......

        ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 14350),
        KEY1 VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
        KEY2 VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
        KEY3 VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (ID)
    );
```

INSERT statement that hibernate generated:

```
insert into Db2Schema.table_entity ( ID, KEY1, KEY2, KEY3, .....) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ......)
```

If it put @Transient annotation on Id field, it works well but I dont want to use @Transient annotation as it will ignore this field all together and I need to use it further in my use case. All I want to do is to ignore this field during insert. I've tried to set insertable=false but it dont work either.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If something is "autogenerated" in the database then it needs to have `GenerationStrategy` of IDENTITY.

Comment: As you suggested, I tried with this but couldn't succeed. Facing same error. I have edited my question with your suggestion as well.

Comment: If you really have IDENTITY strategy and if that COLUMN is correctly defined then your JPA provider will NOT include the column in the INSERT. You post no DDL of the table definition, no SQL of the INSERT, so nothing to say

Comment: My bad, apologies for that. I have now provided the SQL of INSERT, DDL and more detailed error in my question.

Comment: Firstly "insertable"/"updatable" are not needed on any IDENTITY generated field. Secondly, if your JPA provider is still including "ID" in INSERT statements when it is marked as IDENTITY then you should raise a bug on it, since JPA providers should let it be generated in the datastore, and the one I use does this correctly

Comment: I have provided now a POM snippet from my configurations. I am using Hibernate 4.3.11.

Answer (score 1):

Taking IDENTITY field from @Embeddable Class to @Entity Class worked for me.

Its now looks like this:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="table_entity", schema="Db2Schema")
    @DynamicUpdate @DynamicInsert
    public class TableEntity implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="ID")
        private Integer Id;

        @EmbeddedId
        private TableEntityKey tableEntityKey;

        ............ Rest of the entity Fields .............

    }


@Embeddable
public class TableEntityKey implements Serializable{


    @Column(name="key1", length=254)
    private String key1;

    @Column(name="key2", nullable=false, length=256)
    private String key2;

    @Column(name="key3", nullable=false, length=256)
    private String key3;

    ..... getters and setters go here ................

}
```

Comment: which is clearly a fail against the JPA spec because you can only use `@GeneratedValue` on an `@Id` field.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It worked because of DynamicUpdate & DynamicInsert annotations, becuase in the case of an update, ID column dont get changed hence not included in Update statement, and during insert, its value is null and thus not included in Insert Statement.